# I want only the first value for distinct ids to be summed sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database like this:

```
weekid    overage    type    type2
504       400        x       y
504       400        z       y
503       200        x       z
502       100        x       x
502       100        x       y
```

What I want is to get the 400 from weekid 504 to sum with the 200 of weekid 503 and the 100 from weekid 502, I do not want it to sum the other 400 from weekid 504 or 502

So the output should be sum(overage) = 700

basically what i want is something that does a vbscript loop like this

```
do until rs9.eof
    if weekid<>rs.fields("weekid") then
        weekid=rs.fields("weekid")
        overage=overage+rs.fields("overage")
    end if
rs.movenext
loop
```

however it needs to do this in the query, what is the easiest sql query to do this?

also my version of sql server does not seem to support row_number

Comment: What do you need when 2 same weekids have different overage values? Do you need the max of the overages for that weekid OR do you want to include both overages in the sum?

Comment: Based on your question title, what do you mean 1st? Any value, max value, 1st ordered by something? Please clarify

Comment: @Kash Every overage will be the same for each distinct weekid

Comment: @the first row that is displayed does not need to be ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

If the values for same weekids would ALWAYS be the same, then use a).
For the case when the same weekids have different overage values:

a) if you need the different values for the same value to be included in the sum:

```
SELECT  SUM([Overage])
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    [WeekId] ,
                    [Overage]
          FROM      [dbo].[OverageTable]
        ) tmp
```

a) if you need only the max of different values for the same value to be included in the sum:

```
SELECT  SUM([Overage])
FROM    ( SELECT    [WeekId] ,
                    MAX([Overage]) AS [Overage]
          FROM      [dbo].[OverageTable]
          GROUP BY  [WeekId]
        ) tmp
```

Comment: Only works if `overage` is the same for all instances of a given `weekId` - we have not been given enough information to determine if this will always be the case.  This is also kinda hacky, in that it's exploiting behavior intended for a different purpose.

Comment: Agreed. Hence asked OP the same question in my comment. Anyway, i have given 2 possible scenarios he might look for.

Answer (score 0):

That depends what you mean by the first row - data has no inherent order. 
You can tweak the `order by` clause in the below when you decide how you want to order things,.

```
select sum(overage)
from
    (Select overage, row_number() over (partition by weekid order by type, type2) rn
     from yourtable
    ) v
where rn=1
```

Comment: by first row I mean the first row that is given (or just one row), all the overage rows will be the same for each distinct weekids

Comment: @kricket - That's critical information that should have been included in your question.  While most of us seem to be assuming that was the case (or was a possibility), it could have resulted in 'wrong' results.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly choose one value:

```
select sum(overage)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by weekid order by newwid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

If you know all the values are the same, you might prefer an aggregation instead:

```
select sum(overage)
from (select weekid, max(overage) as overage
      from t
      group by weekid
     ) t
```

DON'T DO THE FOLLOWING:

```
select sum(distinct overage)
```

Although this is valid SQL, you will lose weeks that have the same value.

Comment: 'row_number() not a supported aggregate function' apparently my sql server version is to old